# Creating a Poll with Firebase

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polling

So here's a bit of background: my firebase data structure is essentially the root Reference, the question then data for follow ups and responses the user would select from (in the actual poll the idea is that if they select a response then the corresponding follow up would come up for them).

Here's the screenshot of my data structure. 
[image]

So essentially, I'm struggling to discover a method in which I can display the "Active" question for a poll instead of displaying all the questions. There's no particular way in which I can choose a question as the active one in the code because then i would have to update the code every single time their needs to be a change of questions. I'm only using javascript, HTML, and CSS at the moment. Also, I already have an administer page where an administrator can create and update questions.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to filter the questions of the poll?

Comment: How so @RazvanAlex? Thanks for the help.